# unit testing cell is nil

Tags: swift, unit-testing, uicollectionviewcell

***Issue:***

I loaded collectionView with 3 Dummy items. However Cell came back nil, is it because view was never loaded? How do you guys test your collectionViewCell type?

***Code***

```
var window: UIWindow?
var sut: QuestsDataProvider!
var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    bulletinController = BulletinController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    sut = QuestsDataProvider(acceptedQuests: false, completedQuests: false)
    bulletinController.collectionView?.dataSource = sut
    bulletinController.collectionView?.delegate = sut

    window = UIWindow()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = bulletinController
}

func testCellIsQuestCell() {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    guard let count = sut.questManager?.quests.count else {return XCTFail()}
    XCTAssertTrue(cell is QuestCell)
}
```

Edit:

Upon Further testing, I'm able to see the dummy Cell inside my simulator and get a accurate count from `numberOfitems(InSection: Int)`. However I have no visible Cell.

2nd Edit:

After further research, I found out the issue is `collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)` only shows visible cell. Is there any other method for unit testing collection view cell type?

Comment: Have you added `collectionView` to the view hierarchy and set its `frame` so that it's visible? Otherwise, iOS may forgo doing any sort of work for it.

Comment: i updated my question please check if my question makes sense.

Comment: @JeffreyChang did you solve the issue?

Comment: i didn't solve this issue yet. If you have any insight i would love to hear it.

Comment: @JeffreyChang Can you run the View Debugger to see where the cell is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the view object of the view controller before it and its subview components will be fully initialised.

You should be able to just do `let _ = bulletinController.view` in your setup function. it is quite a common approach, see [here](https://clean-swift.com/testing-view-controller-part-1/)

Relevant parts included below

```
func setupCreateOrderViewController()
{
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: bundle)
    createOrderViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CreateOrderViewController") as! CreateOrderViewController
    _ = createOrderViewController.view
}
```

**Quote from link:**

But there are two very, very important things happening on the last line:

- Asking for the view property of createOrderViewController causes the view to be loaded. The viewDidLoad() method is called as a result.
- After the view is loaded, all the IBOutlets are also set up and ready to be used in out tests. For example, you can assert that a text field outlet’s text equal to a string you expect.

EDIT:

You can also just call `loadViewIfNeeded()` on the view controller, which will do the same thing.

> Loads the view controller’s view if it has not yet been loaded.